# Is there any shortcut other than arrow to scroll ipython autocompletion list?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

In jupyter notebook with ipython kernel, when I hit `something.` + `tab` I see autocompletion list.
Is there a way to go next/previous with `ctrl+something` for example without leaving my home row (i.e., without arrow keys)?

Comment: did you solve this by any change?